# Media keys play/pause globally worked in 12.10, not in 13.10

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys

## Laptop media keys

On Asus n55sf laptop, there are a dedicated keys for volume up, volume down, mute, [play/pause], stop, launch (plus a dozen Fn-key combinations).

## In 12.10 most worked.

(Overall is seems unrelated to desktop environment used, stating it for the sake of completeness.)

On Ubuntu 12.10 under XFCE they just worked. That is: when a player like rhythmbox or totem was started, it would alternate between play and pause.

Interestingly, if several were started, they would alternate independently. E.g. use mouse to pause rhythmbox, launch totem, and one hit on [play/pause] key would pause one and resume the other.
Keys Next,Previous and Stop worked as expected in any program.

## In 13.10 most still work, but play/skip related ignored.

On Xubuntu 13.10 (XFCE too) the volume keys work but the [play/pause], stop, next and prev are ignored. Not tried regular Ubuntu 13.10 (Unity).

## Search before you ask

Here are a few facts:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Architecture is ummutable and mentions Ubuntu 9.10. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting is also outdated as it mentions `/usr/share/doc/udev/README.keymap.txt` which no longer exists.
- On 12.10 and 13.10 versions, at XFCE level (as visible by xfconf-query or using xfce4-settings-manager) there are a couple of shortcut for keys like XF86Calculator or XF86TouchpadToggle but *nothing* related to volume prev/next/play/stop, which is okay.
- XF86Audio substring doesn't appear in /etc (which is normal)
- Kernel-level test: "showkey -s" on console shows that keys Next,Play/Pause,Previous,Stop are keycodes 163,164,165,166. Nothing relevant in /etc about that.
- Reports https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1072371 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1012365 suggest to adjust at udev level.
- Alas, the udev tutorials I found ( e.g. https://wiki.debian.org/udev ) don't even mention keyboard.
- A thread in french seems to deal with a similar issue: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1395051. `sudo evtest /dev/input/event3`, in X as well as on plain console, reports events on key pressed and repeats, but nothing when pressing those media keys. Is udev a dead end ?

## Questions

- How did it work in 12.10 ? Through udev ? Something else ?
- Any other hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: sort-of solution.

### Keys and rhythmbox (default Ubuntu 13.10 music player)

As a workaround I was considering to manually set specific events using XFCE shortcut keys facility.

So, I tried `rhythmbox-client` and observed that it failed to remote control rhythmbox as described on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/950743 .

As indicated there, "the problem was solved by enabling MPRIS D-Bus Interface plugin in rhythmbox", which in practice boiled down to :

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugins
```

and restarting rhythmbox.

And then ... the four keys ([play/pause], stop, next and prev) that were ignored now just work.

So, the bug was not at lower levels but just the fact that the "MPRIS D-Bus interface" was unavailable.

### Keys and gmusicbrowser (default Xubuntu 13.10 music player)

Keys did not work immediately with gmusicbrowser.

The symptoms are described on http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.com/2011/11/use-multimedia-keys-with-gmusicbrowser.html with a workaround.

### They don't mix

Keys work with rhythmbox. If launching gmusicbrowser, it does not receive events.
Quitting rhythmbox allows gmusicbrowser to receive events.
Quitting gmusicbrowser does not allow rhythmbox to receive events.

So, it now works for simple cases (one music player at a time).

Answer (score 0):

if you havent figured out by now (as i found this 3 months later) this might answer your question.

1. go to system settings
2. go to keyboard
3. click on the shortcuts tab

down in the menu on the left it will say the different options for the different keyboard shortcuts settings there are and has a custom option as well

1. make your selection on the left
2. click on what keyboard shortcut you want to make (on the right after you make your selection on the left)
3. press the key combination you would like to set
4. done

like stated in the answer above; sometimes these "global" (system wide) shortcuts do not work for certain things. i.e. maximizing certain media players after they have been launched while they are minimized, and things like vlc media player has its own way to set shortcuts in the settings as it will not work with the global media key shortcuts for some reason .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the question I mention `xfce4-settings-manager` which is what is actually running when following your steps in XFCE. Perhaps you meant Unity's equivalent.  Anyway, in the accepted answer, the part regarding `gmusicbrowser` is a scripted way probably similar to what you're describing.

Comment: oh sure, thanks for thanking me. i use unity. glad i could be of some help at least - _ ^